# Is it possible to enable or disable common push notifications from a Flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase-messaging to implement push notifications, but I am not sure how to enable or disable receiving push notifications in the background from a Flutter app. If anyone knows, I would appreciate any advice or URLs to refer to.

There is a discussion about using topic to implement FCM, but in that case, you would send FCM messages using topic instead of token, which could result in sending the message to all users. This could be highly inefficient. If someone has knowledge about this, I would like to hear their opinion.

Comment: Can you subscribe and unsubscribe from a topic?

        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.unsubscribeFromTopic(subscription.name);

Comment: Thank you for the comment.
I've never heard the name "Topic" before, but I believe you can subscribe or unsubscribe.

Comment: I do have a desire to send FCM using tokens rather than topics.

Comment: I sent FCM in the following format, but an error occurred.
`Exception from a finished function: Error: Messaging payload contains an invalid "topic" property. Valid properties are "data" ."`



`const topic = 'highScores';

const message = {
  data: {
    score: '850',
    time: '2:45'
  },
  topic: topic
};`